# Built-in zoom in MathView doesn't work

Tags: android, mathjax

I'm using a MathView to display latex formulas; I got a problem displaying longer formulas because they don't fit on the screen and I don't know how to automatically resize the text. I tried to activate the built-in zoom (like a normal webView), but it doesn't work.

```
formulaDisplayed = (MathView) findViewById(R.id.formula_one);
formulaDisplayed.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Anyone know how to automatically resize the text or how to activate the built-in zoom?